# Using TFS 2013, my web performance test runs fine but same test fails within load test

Tags: testing, tfs, load

I am new to TFS Performance and load test. I have created one web test using the recording feature. When I am running the web test it runs fine but when same test is run from Load Test it fails with QueryStringParameter not found error. Can someone please suggest what could be wrong. My scenario requires loging into Azure website and than few navigations. Please suggest if any pointers.

Thanks
P

Comment: Are you following this [create a load test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release#create-a-load-test) tutorial? You need to use on-premises load test instead of Cloud-based Load Testing with Visual Studio Team Service.

Comment: And since your scenario requires logging into Azure website. Make sure you have an available Azure subscription and have corresponding permissions.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT         Thanks for response Patrick, I have been using Cloud Based load test, why do I have to use on-premises? Can you please elaborate. thanks

Comment: Also load test runs fine if I remove the parameter bindings in web tests , that is weird because it would make sense to use parameter for more than one instance of the same scenario? I am worried it might cause other issue? Is it expected for test to have the actual values instead of binding with the parameters when those are run from load test

Comment: If you are running with **Cloud Based Load test**. Actually it's nothing business with TFS2013 on-premises server. It sets up virtual machines in the cloud that will run your load test. And your web site must be publicly available on the internet for load testing using Visual Studio Team Services to access it. It's bind with your VSTS account [Cloud Based Load Testing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/cloud-load-testing/). Must to say which is not totally free even you aleady have TFS2013 product key, the related [pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/)

Comment: Which  Parameters are you meaning and using such as context parameters or  dynamic parameters? For both it's support with Load Test in Cloud. And how did you bind the parameters with your web test,  is it in a run setting file?